# How to make the total price to go up and down by pressing to the +/- button in stepper?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, function, uistepper

How to create a function in which as the +/- buttons increase, the total cost of the product will increase? I wrote this kind of code but it doesn't count right

```
 @IBOutlet weak var counterlbl: UILabel! // Counter label
 @IBOutlet var costLbl: UILabel! // Price label
 var counter = 1 //Counter which contains the value to increment or decrement(+/-)

let minusTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(minusImageTapped))
        minusBtn.addGestureRecognizer(minusTap)
        minusBtn.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        
//custom UIstepper I used images
        let plusTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(plusImageTapped))
        plusBtn.addGestureRecognizer(plusTap)
        plusBtn.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

```
    //decrement
  @objc func minusImageTapped () {
    let price = costLbl.text
    var priceInt = Int(price!)
        if counter > 1{
           counter -= 1
            let totalPrice = priceInt! / counter
            counterlbl.text = String(counter)
            costLbl.text = String(totalPrice)
            print("minus")
            
        }
    }

//increment
   @objc func plusImageTapped() {
    let price = costLbl.text
    var priceInt = Int(price!)
    counter += 1
    let totalPrice = priceInt! * counter
    counterlbl.text = String(counter)
    costLbl.text = String(totalPrice)
    print("Plus")
}
```

Comment: You haven’t provided us enough information. you have a costLbl and a counterlbl which I assume are IBOutlets to UILabels. You have a variable `counter` which looks like it contains the value you want to increment/decrement. What are these labels for, what is the division/multiplication supposed to do, and what is your code failing to do correctly?

Comment: It looks like your counter and counterlbl UILabel should be incrementing/decrementing correctly based on the code.

Comment: My code should increase the price of the product when I press the stepper, let's say my product price is 5$ when I press the + button of the stepper the product amount then will be equal to 2, and the total price of the product (which is costlbl.text) should be 10$ and vice-versa with the "-" button of stepper but the price will decrease by 5$

Comment: But why are you using division when decreasing the counter, this makes no sense. If you go from 2 to 3 with a price of 5 the total goes from 10 to 15 but if you then go back to 2 then the total will go from 15 to 5 / 2 which is 2.5 (shown as 2) and not 10.

Comment: Yes my bad you're right, but still it doesn't work when i increase the counter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are changing the ***cost per item*** each time...

Let's say you start with `counter = 1` and your `costLbl` has a "5" as its text.

You tap the **plus** image, and your code does this:

```
    price = costLbl.text                // costLbl text is "5"
    priceInt = Int(price)               // priceInt now equals 5
    counter += 1                        // counter now equals 2
    totalPrice = priceInt * counter     // totalPrice now equals 10
```

you then set `costLbl.text = "10"`

so, the next time you tap "plus"...

```
    price = costLbl.text                // costLbl text is "10" !!!!
    priceInt = Int(price)               // priceInt now equals 10 !!!!
    counter += 1                        // counter now equals 3
    totalPrice = priceInt * counter     // totalPrice now equals 30 !!!!
```

and you set `costLbl.text = "30"`

so, the next time you tap "plus"...

```
    price = costLbl.text                // costLbl text is "30" !!!!
    priceInt = Int(price)               // priceInt now equals 30 !!!!
    counter += 1                        // counter now equals 4
    totalPrice = priceInt * counter     // totalPrice now equals 120 !!!!
```

and you set `costLbl.text = "120"`

and on and on.

You need a ***CostPerItem*** label, and a ***TotalPrice*** label.

Then, each time through you get the same "Cost per Item" from the **CostPerItem** label, and display the result of `priceInt * counter` in the **TotalPrice** label.

One thing that may have helped you figure this out sooner would be to put your calculations in a single function... then call that function (with an indicator of "incrementing" or "decrementing"), so you aren't confused about the whole multiply or divide issue.

Take a look at this:

```
class PlusMinusVC: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var costPerItemLbl: UILabel!      // "Cost per Item" label
    @IBOutlet var counterLbl: UILabel!          // "Number of Items" label
    @IBOutlet var totalPriceLbl: UILabel!       // Total Price display label
    
    var counter = 1     // Counter (Number of Items) which contains the value to increment or decrement(+/-)
    
    //decrement
    @objc func minusImageTapped () {
        updateLabels(increment: false)
    }
    
    //increment
    @objc func plusImageTapped() {
        updateLabels(increment: true)
    }

    func updateLabels(increment: Bool) {

        // don't do anything until we make sure we have valid price

        // make sure Cost Per Item label has a string
        if let priceStr = costPerItemLbl.text {
            
            // make sure we get a valid Int
            if let priceInt = Int(priceStr) {

                // if we tapped the minus image,
                //  don't go lower than 1 item
                if increment == false {
                    if counter > 1 {
                        counter -= 1
                    } else {
                        return
                    }
                } else {
                    counter += 1
                }
                
                counterLbl.text = "\(counter)"
                
                let totalPrice = priceInt * counter
                totalPriceLbl.text = "Total: \(totalPrice)"

            }
            
        }
        
    }
    
}
```